# SQL syntax error: no such column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am new to SQL. I am stuck on the error for a while, I hope some one could help me.

```
update roads1f set indoorpathway=PathWay1f.Indoor_pathway where astext(roads1f.geometry)= astext(PathWay1f.Geometry)
```

The error is

> no such column PathWay1f.Indoor_pathway

I checked `PathWay1f` table, it has `Indoor_pathway` column. Did I use the wrong method to reference data in another table?

PathWay1f and roads1f are almost same. The geometry can be considered as the primary key. PathWay1f has a column Indoor_pathway, but roads1f doesn't have. I just want to copy Indoor_pathway from PathWay1f to roads1f.

Comment: Can you provide the definitions of both `roads1f` and `PathWay1f`? Are you selecting data from `PathWay1f`? Where is the portion of your statement that is collecting the data to use for the update?

Comment: You need a `FROM` clause referencing the `Pathway1f` table.

Comment: Actually, PathWay1f and roads1f are almost same. The geometry can be considered as the primary key. PathWay1f has a column Indoor_pathway, but roads1f doesn't have. I just want to copy Indoor_pathway from PathWay1f to roads1f. @gmiley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need  the join

```
update roads1f 
set indoorpathway=( 
        select PathWay1f.Indoor_pathway  
        from PathWay1f
        where astext(roads1f.geometry)= astext(PathWay1f.Geometry))
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks like good, but it takes very long time, and haven't finished yet..   My roads1f table has 50,000 rows. Does it take O(n^2)?

Comment: you have posted  a  question about an error  .. not for performance .. if you have 50.000 the performance depend by several fatcor  .. indexes ... hardware .. and others  ..and  .  if you have not the error this mean that my answer  should be right  then you should rate the asnwer  properly ..

Comment: @chen When the code does what it basically is supposed to do (after using scaisEdge proposal) then it is time to either ask a **separate** specific code question (as scaisEdge implied) with speed aspect here at StackOverflow, or to switch to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @scaisEdge  Thanks! My apology.